# Telegram bot exists or not

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

I've got a PHP site with a database of Bot id and token of them.

Is it possible to check if a Bot exists or not? is it fake or not? from BotID and Token.

I've tried to check `http://telegram.me/_Bot_ID_` page if it exists or showing some `404` error but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know any direct answer for the problem but some tips may help:

1- Telegram bots all end with `bot` word, so others can be omitted
2- You can check the existence of Telegram bot or any account with `telegram.me/BOT_or_ACCOUNT_USERNAME`, but if you're on desktop you should have Telegram desktop. the `telegram.me` itself does not provide information about existence of username, But Telegram app shows a pop up message indicating  that `User @USERNAME not found.`

Comment: Yes, I know , I was *hopping* for a service or an API that filter fake and real `Bot`.